# Can a flat piece of metal, travelling near c and perpendicular to it's direction of motion, create real particles from the virtual ones?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics

Imagine a flat piece of metal travelling at near the speed of light. The flat piece is perpendicular to its direction of motion. Can this piece create for example a real electron-positron pair, by the mechanism of two real photons, emanating from the metal, wich impart enough energy because of the metal's high velocity (in an absolute sense, which is said not to exist, in contrast to the absolute motion through spacetime, which I doubt) to a virtual electron-positron pair, thus creating a real electron-positron pair.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That will not happen. If the sheet of metal is on an inertial world line a simple Lorentz boost puts one on a frame at rest with the sheet. If it is generating particles as seen moving relativistically by one observer it would be generating particles as seen by an observer on the sheet. This would imply any sheet of metal would generate particles from virtual ones.

Comment: One may also ask about the interaction of a object with, for instance, the CMB relative which it has been highly boosted. If the boost is high enough (!) this gives a different answer but the process is the same as in a plain ole' electromagnetic shower induced by a high energy photon because it *is* the start of a boring EM shower. And the boost required is pretty phenomenal.

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell- It's clear that if you perform a Lorenz boost, you can rotate (in Minkowski space)  an inertial frame so that it coincides with the Lorenz rotated rest frame of the sheet of metal. But all other objects in the Universe are not Lorenz rotated, making the sheet and an observer on it, moving in an absolute sense (which you think can't be true, or *isn't* true, in contrast to what I think). So they are not equivalent to all other objects in the Universe (contradicting the equivalence principle). So the observer sees different things than an observer who hasn't been accelerated.

Comment: Like dmckee wrote, the CMB photons in the front (the direction of movement) of the piece of metal have a very high energy, so they certainly create electron-positron pairs out of the vacuum. A piece of metal at rest (thus one which through it's entire "life" hasn't observed acceleration) "sees" an equal CMB in front of him as at his backside. The CMB resembles a little bit the aether (but the velocity of light is not affected to observers moving through it). But you cán tell by observing it if your motion through space is absolute, which doesn't contradict absolute motion through spacetime.

Comment: If one includes external factors such as radiation, then clearly a highly relativistic object will scatter off particles and radiation. If the Lorentz gamma factor is high enough you will get pair production. However, from a pure special relativity perspective there will be no interaction with the vacuum, for instance, or such thing that generates particles from a highly boosted object.